# Getting HEX data at specific offset for multiple files (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, hex, openfiledialog

I have working code that will examine a file and pull the correct hex data at a given offset. I have modified this code to work with "OpenFileDialog's" multiselect.

However, my code is stuck reading the first file, over and over again, thus each file has the same HEX output.

I need this to parse through each file discover in the OpenFileDialog.

Currently, what ever the first file in the list "Multiselected" is the only file that is read, over and over. None of the other files get examined.

My code is below:

```
Int_openDiag()

        Dim dr As DialogResult = Me.OpenDialog.ShowDialog()
        If (dr = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

            Dim Files As String
            For Each Files In OpenDialog.SafeFileNames
                         Try

                    Using OpenedFile As New BinaryReader(File.Open(OpenDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                        ' Loop through length of file.
                        Dim fileLength As Long = OpenedFile.BaseStream.Length
                        Dim byteCount As Integer = 0
                        Dim pos As Long = "&H" + TextBox1.Text                  'Offset to scan. (Scan starting point)
                        OpenedFile.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                        While pos < fileLength And byteCount < requiredBytes
                            value(byteCount) = OpenedFile.ReadByte()
                            pos += 1
                            byteCount += 1
                        End While

                        displayValue = BitConverter.ToString(value)

                        Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(Files)
                        newItem.SubItems.Add(displayValue)
                        newItem.SubItems.Add("0x" + TextBox1.Text)
                        ListView1.Items.Add(newItem)

                    End Using
                Catch SecEx As Security.SecurityException

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Next Files

        End If
```

Can someone please help me figure out why?

I've tried adding the "Files" string variable here:

```
Using OpenedFile As New BinaryReader(File.Open(Files, FileMode.Open))
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------^

But that simply renders:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
```

Comment: Try changing your For loop statement to: `For Each Files In OpenDialog.FileNames` - Then when opening the files do as you said: `Using OpenedFile As New BinaryReader(File.Open(Files, FileMode.Open))`

Comment: The `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileNames` property contains only the names of the files. You require the full path, which is why you need to use `.FileNames` instead.

Answer (score 3):

SafeFileNames does not include the path, so your BinaryReader can't find the file (it's probably looking in the bin\debug folder).

Try changing it to:

```
For Each Files In ofd.FileNames
  Using OpenedFile As New BinaryReader(File.Open(Files, FileMode.Open))
```

because the FileNames collection does contain the path.  If you still want to use the SafeFileNames, then you will have to use Path.Combine and put the folder path back into your file name yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, but now my listview is displaying the entire file path as opposed to the file name only, Will the path.combine allow me to A.) get this to work, and B.) use file name only for the list output?

Comment: @level42 Obviously, for the ListView item, you only add the file name without the path.  Use Path.GetFileName for that.  If you still need that path information later, store it in the ListView item's Tag property.

Comment: I added: newItem.SubItems.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Files)) and it seems to work if I open a single file. If I try to open a second file, or multiple files, my application seems to lock up. (No debug errors)

Comment: @level42 I can't see what you are doing unless you update your question with the code.  If this is a different issue, then it might require a new question to be asked and close this question out if the file name issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to sort out the issue, I changed the bytecount to .5 instead of 1 (for some apparent reason) and it caused the app to lock up. I've reverted the change and the path.getfilename, is now working. Thanks again